# Firebase Realtime Cloud Function - Cannot read property of null snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've gone through all similar answers with no luck, but for some reason, my Firebase cloud function is returning a snapshot.val() of null. The first console.log is printing correctly giving the following:

> User:8Ch7RGBnMrNiQlS6g8xKcDO3cr93 is following:
>   WpKoFs1UgHTCZegMwjkXyXqrBTz1

I will attach the structure of the database at the bottom. This is the error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fcmToken' of null at admin.database.ref.once.snapshot

```
exports.observeFollowing = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/following/{followingId}').onCreate((context) => {

var uid = context.params.uid
var followingId = context.params.followingId

console.log('User:' + uid + ' is following: ' + followingId)

return admin.database().ref('/users/{followingId}').once('value', snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    var userWeAreFollowing = snapshot.val()
    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: "You have a new follower",
            body: "It's Tom"
        },
        token: userWeAreFollowing.fcmToken
    };
    admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        return response
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
})
```

})
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`snapshot.val()` will be null when there is no data at the location you requested, which is definitely the case here.

Here's where your query location of "/users/{followingId}" is specified:

```
admin.database().ref('/users/{followingId}')
```

That string is being taken literally.  There is no variable substitution going on here.  If you wanted to put `followingId` into that string, you'll need to tell JavaScript to do that correctly:

```
admin.database().ref(`/users/${followingId}`)
```

Note the backticks for string delimiter and the way of specifying values to include within the string.

You were likely mixing up the placeholder syntax for the function definition.

Comment: Thank you Doug, however are you sure this is the case for Firebase Cloud functions. Even in  their documentation and dozens of other examples I have looked at, string delimination is not required. Using this method actually now causes more errors, as the first console log is no longer printing. 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: I am positive. This is a common mistake.  As I said at the very end of the answer, you are likely mixing up the placeholder syntax for the function definition. It's not the same as JavaScript string interpolation.